# Windows Phone 8.1 flow container for dynamic buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, gridview

SOF Tribe,

I have a request for the identity of a flow container into which I can pour an indeterminate number of dynamically created XAML buttons. Said buttons should wrap the text as closely as possible (I think I have a template for this). But the buttons should wrap like a gridview, but run like a stackpanel. Does anyone know a container that will allow me to accomplish what the image portrays?

Currently, for the existing image below, I'm using a gridview, but the gridview sets a specific width but does flow unevenly. A stackpanel has the desired end-to-butt style but won't wrap. So, any ideas?

[image: Auto wrapping flow container]

Answer (score 2):

There is what is called the UniversalWrapPanel made by Greg Stoll. So, that's the direction I'll be taking. Now however, I've got the last little bit to tackle. How to get the bound data to respect the parent container's ability to wrap content and not just stack it up in a vertical column.

The below XAML gives me the below image result which is not quite what I want. Statically added buttons work just fine to the UniversalWrapPanel. But trying to get a binding and ItemsSource to work, well, that's beyond me at this time.

[image]

```
<support:UniversalWrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="GridViewRecipients" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonLozengeStyle}" Content="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</support:UniversalWrapPanel>
```

OK, so a bit more searching and I found this:

http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/02/20/Creating-a-WrapPanel-for-your-Windows-Runtime-apps.aspx

and so here is the correct way to reference the UniversalWrapPanel within the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="GridViewRecipients" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <support:UniversalWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="DodgerBlue"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonLozengeStyle}" Content="{Binding FullName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For the result of:

[image]